# Passing string array from jQuery to asp.net razor syntax website and receiving it in server side code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, razor

I have a VS2012 website of razor syntax. I have some divs, containing text paragraph. I make them  editable via the following jQuery:

```
   if (cmsAuthenticated==true) $(".cmsClass").prop('contentEditable', true);
```

The logged-in user can now edit them. After editing those divs the user clicks on the submit button.

QUESTION: I want to pass the following set of information to server side code, for each editable div:

- Contents: The contents of the div the user just edited
- FileName: The name of text file in which I will update the newly edited data. e.g. 'Page1_Text05.txt'
- Path: The path of that updating file. e.g. 'cms/TextFiles/'

I have the following block of razor code which will save the editted content in its appropriate files:

```
@{
    if (IsPost)
    {
        //Here I will put the code after your kind help to catch the array sent from jQuery
        //Lets suppose I received the data in array named 'DivData' which have 3 columns contents,path,filename for each editable div on the page.

        for(i=0; i<DivData.length; i++)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath("~/" + DivData[i][1] + DivData[i][2]), DivData[i][0]);
            //e.g. DivData[i][1] is "cms/TextFiles/"
            //e.g. DivData[i][2] is "Page1_Text05.txt"
            //e.g. DivData[i][1] is "Some edited content entered by the user"
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.
Please note that everything else is working on my website. I have tested a successfull 'WRITE' of a single file because I passed the contents from jQuery to csharp via a hidden field value. BUT the problem comes when I have x-number of divs and each have 3-set of information.

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an extract of your html.

However,  if you have more than one records (div array) for file - I think you have you will do something like this:

```
var files= []; // create array here
var divarray = $("#divID");
$.each(divarray, function (index, div) {
         var jsonData = {
                    'Name': div.Name,
                    'Path': div.Path,
                }
        files.push(jsonData); //push values here
    });
```

then you can pass as a string.

```
        jsonData = JSON.stringify(files);
```

I am assuming here that you are using jQuery with AJAX call.

```
  $.ajax({
                        url: "/mvccontroller path", //make sure the path is correct
                        cache: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: jsonData,
                        success: function (response) {
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I could not understand your reply.

Comment: I want to pass a multi dimensional array of x-number of rows. Containing 3 set of informations in each row. (1)Path, (2)Filename and (3)Some text.

Comment: I am a newby please tell me in detail when you say "then you can pass as a string. jsonData = JSON.stringify(files);" HOW-What syntax

Comment: I am NOT creating an MVC app. I craeted a website in VS-2012... File --> New --> Website --> Visual C# --> ASP.Net Empty Website

Comment: It is a simple .cshtml website. MOST of my website works with jQuery. The ONLY reason I need the server side code is to 'WRITE/Modify' text files placed on the server. These text files contain text/paragraphs etc which is loaded in certain divs via jQuery.

Comment: The user of my website can edit these paragraphs contained in these particular divs. My nightmare is the syntax of the send call (which you just gave me and so much thanks for that)... PLUS... The syntax of the receive in razor and how to convert it to array again

Comment: For simplicity LETS FORGET ABOUT the text files etc. Lets just focus on the nightmarish issue..... Which is..... I need to send a multi-dimensional array via $.ajax to csharp on click of submit button.

Comment: I dont have any mvccontroller. So what should i put in the url:

Comment: The jQuery script is in the same page where the @{razor code} in which I expect to catch the array sent via @.ajax call

Comment: please paste me the html

Comment: PLEASE Mr codebased..., Do state the syntax of the razor code which will catch this kind of json object after postback call to same page again. How will it convert to array. Please help me.

Comment: Ok. But let me clean it first. Otherwise you may get lost in lots of useless jibberish. Please wait